# Add more images on Canvas with Kinetic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

Im making an app, but I ve met the problem. I need when I hit a button add new point (image) on my Canvas. Here is a code:

```
var ID = 0;
var points = [];

function addPoint(){
points.push({id: ID, posX: 0, posY: 0, url: "img/point.png"});
ID++;
showPoints();
}

function showPoints(){
var img = new Array();
var point = new Array();
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'cvsCroatia',
    width: 574,
    height: 508
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

for(var j=0; j < ID; j++){
    img[j] = new Image();
    img[j].src = 'img/point.png';
    img[j].onload = (function(){
        point[j] = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: points[j].posX,
            y: points[j].posY,
            image: img[j],
            width: 13,
            height: 13,
            name:  img[j],
            draggable: true
        });
    });
    layer.add(point[j]);

}   
stage.add(layer);
}
```

But i got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'index' of undefined (kinetic-v4.4.0.min.js:29)

Have you got any idea, what is wrong? Thx for answers. Alan..

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new Array(); // the simplest solution is to make img visible outside your function
function showPoints(){
    // var img = new Array();        // HERE img is a LOCAL variable, only visible to the showPoints() function
    var point = new Array();        
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'cvsCroatia',
    width: 574,
    height: 508
});
```

Comment: you should actually make everything in this function global scope

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, i put all variables to the global scope, but unfortunately got the same error..

```
 var ID = 0;
 var points = [];

 var img = new Array();
 var point = new Array();

 function showPoints(){
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'cvsCroatia',
    width: 574,
    height: 508
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

for(var j=0; j < ID; j++){
    img[j] = new Image();
    img[j].src = 'img/point.png';
    img[j].onload = (function(){
        point[j] = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: points[j].posX,
            y: points[j].posY,
            image: img[j],
            width: 13,
            height: 13,
            name:  img[j],
            draggable: true
        });
    });
    layer.add(point[j]);

}   
stage.add(layer);
 }

  function addPoint(){
points.push({id: ID, posX: 0, posY: 0, url: "img/point.png"});
ID++;
showPoints();
}
```